# Set RabbitMq .outq as durable with ServiceStack

Tags: rabbitmq, servicestack

Our queues are automatically created when calling mqServer.CreateMessageQueueClient().Publish(). Recently we had an issue with a RabbitMq server going down and since ServiceStack does not create the outq as durable, the queue data was lost. Is there a way to change the queue to durable?  I believe this has to be done in ServiceStack since that's where the queues are created.

Perhaps I'm approaching the issue from the wrong direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.OutQ` is [registered as a non-durable topic](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/58a5e7f29eb512a2b26df588a21f66f071d64d3f/src/ServiceStack.RabbitMq/RabbitMqExtensions.cs#L45), it's only meant for alerting connected consumers each time a [Service with no Response](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Rabbit-MQ#messages-with-no-responses-are-sent-to-outq-topic) has been executed.

The `.OutQ` Topic is designed to be transient and only used for notification purposes to signal that a request has been processed, it's not meant to be relied on as a durable queue for persisting all Request DTO's processed.

If your [Service instead returns a Response DTO](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Rabbit-MQ#messages-with-responses-are-published-to-the-response-inq) the Response DTO would then be persisted in the durable `Response.inq` queue.